# Why the code has no cout?

Tags: c++, c++11

I can compile the code with g++, as well as cin is good. However, I get no output after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> and I can continue inputting words. What's the problem?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<string, size_t> word_count;
    string word;
    while (cin>>word) {
        ++word_count[word];
    }
    for (auto &w : word_count) {
        cout<<w.first<<" occurs "<<w.second<<" times"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "the code has no cout" and "I get no cout"? I see plenty of uses of `cout` in this code.

Answer (score 4):

`while(cin>>word)` loops as long as you're entering a valid string. Empty string is still a valid string, hence the loop never ends.

Answer (score 4):

You  need to send a EOF character, such as CTRL-D to stop the loop.

Comment: Is there any way to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> as a EOF character?

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more research, I realized that the prior code I wrote was incorrect. You should not be using cin <<, rather you should be using getline(std::cin, std::string);

Your code should look like:

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<string>
 #include<map>
 using namespace std;

 int main() {
 map<string, size_t> word_count;
string word;
while (getline(cin, word)) {
    if(word.empty()) {
     break;
     }
    ++word_count[word];
}
for (auto &w : word_count) {
    cout<<w.first<<" occurs "<<w.second<<" times"<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

Let me know if this causes any errors, I ran a few test cases and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: You don't need the `if` statement; the code won't enter the body of the loop when the input is `"escapeSequence"`.

Comment: Is there any way to jump out of the loop with a single 'enter'?

Comment: @zhaokai If you change the termination string to an empty string, "", then when the user enters an empty string (by pressing enter with no input), the loop will end.

Comment: Sorry to say ,but it seems not a right solution. I tried empty string "" with g++, but `ctrl + D` is still needed to jump out. The code is copied from _C++ Primer_, can it be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify how many words you want to be entered. And you are in infinite loop. So you can:

```
unsigned counter = 10;  // enter 10 words

while ( cin >> word && --counter ) {
    ++word_count[word];
}
```

output:

```
zero
one
one
one
one
two
three
three
three
four
one occurs 4 times
three occurs 3 times
two occurs 1 times
zero occurs 1 times
```